# whmcs server-side pagination

Tags: datatables, whmcs

I'm working with WHMCS and I notice that list views are not working well. 
That's because in the clientarea's list views I have tousans thousands of records to display and the DataTables is crashing.
Is there a way to paginate from the server-side? I will appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: let' say you are viewing the Domains list page, you can use ClientAreaPage hook to create a variable to load a "paged" copy of domains:

```php
add_hook( 'ClientAreaPage', 1, function( $vars )
{
    $myVars = array();
    if (App::getCurrentFilename() == 'clientarea' && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'domains') {
        $domains2 = array();
        foreach($vars['domains'] as $k => $domain) {
            if ($k < 3) {//your code to handle pagination
                $domains2[] = $domain;
            }

        }
        $myVars['domains2'] = $domains2;
        $myVars['currentpage'] = 1;
    }

    return $myVars;


});
```

In clientareadomains.tpl (template file), you need to change $domains to $domains2:

```
{foreach key=num item=domain from=$domains2}
```

Of course, it is not simple task, you need to handle pagination in the hook and the tpl files.

Hope it helps.